# CentOS 6 - Codeigniter - HMVC - Not Found

Tags: codeigniter, htaccess, centos

Boa tarde

Eu estou desenvolvendo um sistema com o Codeigniter 2.X, e utilizo o conceito de HMVC.

As minhas pastas estão assim:

```
->system/
.htaccess
->application/
   ->controllers
       ->...
   ->model
       ->...
   ->view
       ->...
   ->modules
       ->sistema
           ->controllers
               ->...
           ->model
               ->...
           ->view
               ->...
```

O meu .htaccess está assim:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|css|js|images|robots.txt|includes|relatorio) 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /codeigniter/index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Então, ao acessar a página inicial (ex.:http://exemplo.com.br/produto), o codeigniter funciona normalmente.

Contudo, ao acessar as página do sistema (ex.:http://exemplo.com.br/sistema/login), o codeigniter não funciona. Ele apresente o seguinte erro:

```
Not Found
The requested URL /codeigniter/sistema/login was not found on this server.
```

Porém, no meu PC (windows 7 e xampp) ele funciona legal, mas quando eu passo para o meu servidor (CentOS 6 X86_64) ele apresente o erro já mencionado.

Eu não configurei virtual host.

Desde já agradeço.

Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Tente modificar o seu htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|css|js|images|robots.txt|includes|relatorio)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Olá amigo, primeiramente, obrigado pela ajuda! Mas infelizmente não funcionou, ainda continua dando o mesmo erro. Será que é alguma configuração de virtual host?

Comment: Ou tem alguma coisa relacionada com a permissão dos arquivos ou do .htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

Consegui arrumar. Não sei bem ao certo aonde estava o problema, mas as minhas ações foram as seguintes:

- Eu configurei o arquivo httpd, para aceitar a leitura do arquivo .htaccess;
- E eu criei o arquivo .htaccess direto no linux;

Agradeço a ajuda de todos... Obrigado